# Angular posting FormData to .Net Core webAPI are always null

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, form-data

I have a file uploader component in angular that posts a file and a json object string to a web api controller. unfortunately the values on the server are always null.

Here is the angular method used for upload :

```
  public upload(event: any): void {

        const file = event.target.files[0];
        const formData = new FormData();
    
        var product = {
          productCode: '009',
          productName: 'Test Product Name',
          clientKey: '616f1d97-6798-459a-957f-6e6476aa3c82',
          providerId: 1
        };
    
        formData.append('file', file, file.name);
        formData.append('body', JSON.stringify(product));
    
        var headers = { headers:{
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'TimeStamp' : '2022-05-05T16:50:36'
        }}
        this.http.post('http://localhost:9913/api/internal/testProduct/Add', formData, headers)
        .pipe(
          map(res => console.log('got response', res),
          catchError(error => of(console.error('got error', error)))))
          .subscribe(() => console.log('next'), error => console.log(error));
      }
```

And the web api controller method:

```
[HttpPost("Add")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddProduct([FromForm] AddProductEntity addProductEntity)
{
    ProductRequestContract addNewProductRequestContract = new ProductRequestContract();
    
    var requestObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductRequestContract>(addProductEntity.body);
    if (requestObj == null)
    {
        return base.BadRequest("Not valid product");
    }
  
    #region upload file to temp folder
    if (addProductEntity.file != null)
    {
        var uploadFileResult = SaveImage(addProductEntity.file);
        if (!uploadFileResult)
        {
            return BadRequest("Error saving the file.");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    return Ok();
}
```

the parameter **AddProductEntity addProductEntity** are always null, why web api model binder is unable to match form data sent in the request?
Note: AddProductEntity  is a simple DTO class has 2 props which matches the form data values:

```
 public class AddProductEntity
    {
        public IFormFile file { get; set; }
        public string body { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You can't use application/json content-type for form data with a file. Use multipart/form-data.

Comment: I tried this before not working still null

Comment: There are probably other issues, like json stringifying your form values. That should be form url encoded instead of json.

Comment: Can you please clarify further?

Comment: I'm not available to work out a complete answer. I think you will find useful info by searching "angular post multipart/form-data"